# Jenkins - avoid SCM polling loop with AssemblyVersion change

Tags: git, svn, jenkins, version-control, merge

I am using Jenkins to manage a pet project of mine.

I am using svn as the SCM, and polling minutely on trunk to fire off a CI build.

I am using the Change Assembly Version plugin to put custom version numbers into the build (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Change+Assembly+Version).   The version numbers capture date, build number, and svn revision number.

The process goes like this:

1. Develop with assembly version = 0.0.0.0
2. Merge from feature branch into trunk.
3. Jenkins polls svn trunk branch.
4. Jenkins downloads trunk HEAD to a clean workspace.
5. Jenkins updates workspace AssemblyInfo files. Version is 1.<yyD>.<SVN#>.<Build#>.
6. Build solution.
7. Deploy solution to staging environment.
8. Create a tag branch for the build.
9. Svn Switch, and commit the assembly info changes into the tag branch (so the version is captured in svn).

Here's the problem though - I'm polling trunk, so I can't update trunk with the new version number after the CI build. Not sure that I'd want to either, except to say it'd make tracking branches more convenient to know the last jenkins version.

What is the best practice?  Keep the new version numbers only in tag?  Should the version numbers get pushed back into trunk?  And if so, how can I do that while polling trunk for a build?